# Can't get sound file to play in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func cowButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let soundFileSeleced : String = soundArray[0]
    print(soundFileSeleced)
    playSound()
}
func playSound() {
    let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cowSound", withExtension: ".wav")

    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

I can't get my sound to play. What's wrong with my code? I get the message:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: It means soundURL is nil. Chech the extension or if the name is correctly spelled. And no need of dot (.) When giving file type.

Answer (score 0):

Check your syntax on the `let soundURL` line. Pretty sure `withExtension` shouldn't have the `.` in it.

Try this?

`let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cowSound", withExtension: "wav")`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn’t work either :/